# Audit full text activity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, audit

I need to find when and which user created full text catalog, and who added/modified/deleted the columns (that were full text indexed) in that full text catalog.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use DDL event groups that can be used to run a DDL trigger or an event notification, and also the Transact-SQL statements they cover.

Refer [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for more details on what can be tracked.

I have posted an answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41614/can-i-get-notification-when-event-occur/41622#41622) for How to get notified when a deadlock occurs using Event notification. The concept is similar and can be applied to audit Full text catalog.