# How to convert an XML deadlock file into a graph or something readable?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, xml

I'm looking for a easy or manageable way to read an XML file, specifically the XML output for SQL Server deadlocks.  I have some servers that are not being monitored for various reasons.

I found the following code on the interwebz, but its output is nothing but XML.

```
CREATE TABLE #errorlog (
                        LogDate DATETIME 
                        , ProcessInfo VARCHAR(100)
                        , [Text] VARCHAR(MAX)
                        );

DECLARE @tag VARCHAR (MAX) , @path VARCHAR(MAX);

INSERT INTO #errorlog EXEC sp_readerrorlog;

SELECT @tag = text
FROM #errorlog 
WHERE [Text] LIKE 'Logging%MSSQL\Log%';

DROP TABLE #errorlog;

SET @path = SUBSTRING(@tag, 38, CHARINDEX('MSSQL\Log', @tag) - 29);

SELECT 
    CONVERT(xml, event_data).query('/event/data/value/child::*') AS DeadlockReport,
    CONVERT(xml, event_data).value('(event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime') 
    AS Execution_Time
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(@path + '\system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)
WHERE OBJECT_NAME like 'xml_deadlock_report';
```

Is there a way to take the raw XML output from this T-SQL code and display it as a deadlock graph or more easily readable text?

Comment: Try saving the XML as a file with an extension of xdl and then open in SSMS

Comment: To get it into tabular form you can use http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/deadlocks/shred-deadlock-graph/

Comment: @ScottHodgin That worked!  It kills me to know that I've been in IT as long as I have and didn't think about file extension trick :|  I should've known better, thank you!

Comment: Wanna receive *.xdl files in your Inbox in near real-time? It's fairly simple with [event notifications](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2017/06/Handling-SQL-Server-Deadlocks-With-Event-Notifications.html)

Comment: @ScottHodgin this works: changing the xml extension to xdl. . But also, delete the outer tags event, data, type value. the outer tag should be <deadlock>.

Comment: Sql Sentry Plan Explorer does a nice job of displaying deadlock graphs.

Comment: @MartinSmith This is the only working solution I have found to get it into tabular format. Thank you very much for sharing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bcp out and save it as `.xdl`. Many ways you can do it .. e.g. BCP OUT (I am using [xp_cmdshell](http://www.midnightdba.com/DBARant/xp_cmdshell-isnt-evil/) but you can use powershell or any other method).

[Borrowing code from my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41622/8783) (You need to adjust the code as per your requirement)  :

> -- bcp out as .xdl file. This is the deadlock graph that will be emailed. Note that it will be overwritten everytime !!

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell ''BCP.exe "SELECT  [Deadlockgraph].query(''''/TextData/deadlock-list'''') FROM dba_db.dbo.Deadlock where Notified = 0" queryout "d:\logs\deadlock.xdl" -c -q -T -Slocalhost''; ---- change localhost ..with the servername\instance or servername !!
```

Comment: Thank you, Kin.  I can see how this method could be very useful!