# Queries involved in deadlock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-mail

Is it possible to send queries involved in a deadlock via db mail alert in SQL Server 2005 on mail?

If it is possible, then what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I have a full script that you can use with proper credit - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41622/8783

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Event Notifications, and have the queue reader send email using sp_smtp_sendmail? https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2017/06/Handling-SQL-Server-Deadlocks-With-Event-Notifications.html